# Default export as global variable Typescript 1.8 --module UMD

Tags: javascript, typescript, umd

I am writing an NPM module that exports a single file. I have set the `--module` flag to `umd`. I would like to expose the default export of this file as a global variable.

**Is it possible to export a UMD module as a global variable in Typescript 1.8?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy is to restructure your module as a namespace so that it acts as a global, and add a custom build step which adds an `export default yourNameSpace;` to your file to create a modular version.